# Writing to a database in the ProgramData folder

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, programdata

I am making a firefox extension that allows me to write to a database that is then accessed by a c# program. I found this to be the easiest way for the two to communicate. Now I need the database to reside in the programdata folder so that everything works well when installed on a clients PC. I am not sure how to go about doing that. I know it's simple from c# but I don't know how from javascript.

Comment: What code have you already tried? Please *[edit] the question* to include your source code in the question. Please see [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Which folder, exactly, are you wanting to access? Are you wanting to use the *profile-directory/extension-data/MyExtension* directory which is the "normal" data directory for your extension?

Comment: @Makyen I hadn't really tried any code for writing there because I am relatively new to javascript. I found info for writing to a database from an extension but nothing on doing it in programdata so I was lost and came here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want this path from Firefox addon:

```
var path_progData = Services.dirsvc.get('CmPrgs', Ci.nsIFile).path;
```

This will give you:

- `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs` - tested on 8.1 (im guessing its same for Win7 and 8, not sure about Win7 though)
- `C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Start Menu\Programs` - for WinXP
- `?` - For WinVista (i have a vista machine but no access right now, will update this later)

You might prefer `CmAppData` which gives you just `C:\ProgramData` on Win8.1

#### Project to collect Firefox special paths on all platforms

So a couple months ago I went through all the special path keywords in Firefox source, I tried to catch them all, I might have missed some, if I did please mention it so we can improve this. My goal was to write something so I can run on all platforms to and see what the special paths were.

This is the code I came up with, can copy paste and run from scratchpad in browser environment: (btw the paths differ based on if your profile is relative to Profiles directory or if it is an absolute path profile) (also if you use the portable version of Firefox the paths differ) (not all paths just some, but in case of portable they are a bit crazy) (portable Firefox only available for Windows)

```
var DSP = Cc["@mozilla.org/file/directory_service;1"].getService(Ci.nsIProperties);
var keywords = [];
var str = [];


function doit() {
    for (var i=0; i<keywords.length; i++) {
        str.push('Keyword: "' + keywords[i] + '"');
        try {
           var methodFU = FileUtils.getFile(keywords[i], ['']);
            str[str.length-1] += '|FU = "' + methodFU.path + '"';
        } catch(ex) {
            str[str.length-1] += '|FU = "' + ex.message + '"';
        }
        try {
           var methodDS = DSP.get(keywords[i], Ci.nsIFile);
            str[str.length-1] += '|DS = "' + methodDS.path + '"';
        } catch(ex) {
            str[str.length-1] += '|DS = "' + ex.message + '"';
        }
    }
var gClipboardHelper = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/widget/clipboardhelper;1"].getService(Components.interfaces.nsIClipboardHelper);
gClipboardHelper.copyString(str.join('\n'))
    console.log(str.join('\n'));
}

var keywords = [
    //http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/xpcom/io/nsAppDirectoryServiceDefs.h
    'AppRegF',
    'AppRegD',
    'DefRt',
    'PrfDef',
    'current',
    'default',
    'DefProfRt',
    'DefProfLRt',
    'ARes',
    'AChrom',
    'APlugns',
    'SrchPlugns',
    'AChromDL',
    'APluginsDL',
    'SrchPluginsDL',
    'SHARED',
    'PrefD',
    'PrefF',
    'MetroPrefF',
    'PrefDL',
    'ExtPrefDL',
    'PrefDOverride',
    'ProfD',
    'ProfLD',
    'UChrm',
    'UsrSrchPlugns',
    'LclSt',
    'UPnls',
    'UMimTyp',
    'cachePDir',
    'BMarks',
    'DLoads',
    'SrchF',
    'XPIClnupD',
    'indexedDBPDir',
    'permissionDBPDir',
    //http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/xpcom/io/nsDirectoryServiceDefs.h
    'Home',
    'TmpD',
    'CurWorkD',
    'Home',
    'Desk',
    'CurProcD',
    'XCurProcD',
    'XpcomLib',
    'GreD',
    'SysD',
    'Trsh',
    'Strt',
    'Shdwn',
    'ApplMenu',
    'CntlPnl',
    'Exts',
    'Fnts',
    'Prfs',
    'Docs',
    'ISrch',
    'DfltDwnld',
    'ULibDir',
    'UsrDsk',
    'LocDsk',
    'UsrApp',
    'LocApp',
    'UsrDocs',
    'LocDocs',
    'UsrIntrntPlgn',
    'LoclIntrntPlgn',
    'UsrFrmwrks',
    'LocFrmwrks',
    'UsrPrfs',
    'LocPrfs',
    'Pct',
    'Mov',
    'Music',
    'IntrntSts',
    'WinD',
    'ProgF',
    'DeskV',
    'Progs',
    'Cntls',
    'Prnts',
    'Pers',
    'Favs',
    'Strt',
    'Rcnt',
    'SndTo',
    'Buckt',
    'Strt',
    'DeskP',
    'Drivs',
    'NetW',
    'netH',
    'Fnts',
    'Tmpls',
    'CmStrt',
    'CmPrgs',
    'CmDeskP',
    'CmAppData',
    'AppData',
    'LocalAppData',
    'PrntHd',
    'CookD',
    'DfltDwnld',
    'Docs',
    'Pict',
    'Music',
    'Vids',
    'Locl',
    'LibD',
    'XDGDesk',
    'XDGDocs',
    'XDGDwnld',
    'XDGMusic',
    'XDGPict',
    'XDGPubSh',
    'XDGTempl',
    'XDGVids',
    'DfltDwnld',
    'DrvD',
    //http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-release/source/toolkit/mozapps/update/nsUpdateService.js#76
    'GreD',
    'UpdRootD',
    'XREExeF',
    //http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-release/source/toolkit/mozapps/update/tests/shared.js#55
    'ProfDS',
    'ProfD',
    'GreD',
    'XCurProcD',
    'XREExeF',
    'UpdRootD',
    //http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-release/source/xpcom/build/nsXULAppAPI.h
    'UAppData',
    'XREExtDL',
    'XREExeF',
    'started',
    'ProfDS',
    'started',
    'ProfLDS',
    'XRESysLExtPD',
    'XRESysSExtPD',
    'XREUSysExt',
    'XREAppDist',
    'UpdRootD',
    'UpdArchD',
    'OSUpdApplyToD'
];

doit();
```

So the special path words are in the array `keywords`. It would be awesome to know all the paths for all platforms.

This code above yields this on Win8.1, it copies to clipboard so can just run and paste here.

**Relative Profile (regular method)**

- Win 8.1

  ```
  Keyword: "AppRegF"|FU = "C:\Users\Vayeate\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\registry.dat"|DS = "C:\Users\Vayeate\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\registry.dat"
  Keyword: "AppRegD"|FU = "C:\Users\Vayeate\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox"|DS = "C:\Users\Vayeate\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox"
  Keyword: "DefRt"|FU = "Component returned failure code: 0x80520015 (NS_ERROR_FILE_ACCESS_DENIED) [nsIFile.create]"|DS = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\browser\defaults"
  Keyword: "PrfDef"|FU = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\defaults\pref"|DS = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\defaults\pref"
  Keyword: "current"|FU = "Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [nsIProperties.get]"|DS = "Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [nsIProperties.get]"
  Keyword: "default"|FU = "Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [nsIProperties.get]"|DS = "Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [nsIProperties.get]"
  Keyword: "DefProfRt"|FU = "C:\Users\Vayeate\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles"|DS = "C:\Users\Vayeate\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles"
  Keyword: "DefProfLRt"|FU = "C:\Users\Vayeate\AppData\Local\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles"|DS = "C:\Users\Vayeate\AppData\Local\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles"
  Keyword: "ARes"|FU = "Component returned failure code: 0x80520015 (NS_ERROR_FILE_ACCESS_DENIED) [nsIFile.create]"|DS = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\browser\res"
  Keyword: "AChrom"|FU = "Component returned failure code: 0x80520015 (NS_ERROR_FILE_ACCESS_DENIED) [nsIFile.create]"|DS = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\browser\chrome"
  Keyword: "APlugns"|FU = "Component returned failure code: 0x80520015 (NS_ERROR_FILE_ACCESS_DENIED) [nsIFile.create]"|DS = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\browser\plugins"
  Keyword: "SrchPlugns"|FU = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\browser\searchplugins"|DS = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\browser\searchplugins"
  Keyword: "AChromDL"|FU = "Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [nsIProperties.get]"|DS = "Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [nsIProperties.get]"
  Keyword: "APluginsDL"|FU = "Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [nsIProperties.get]"|DS = "Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [nsIProperties.get]"
  Keyword: "SrchPluginsDL"|FU = "Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [nsIProperties.get]"|DS = "Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [nsIProperties.get]"
  Keyword: "SHARED"|FU = "Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [nsIProperties.get]"|DS = "Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [nsIProperties.get]"
  Keyword: "PrefD"|FU = "C:\Users\Vayeate\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\qekfxcdm.Unnamed Profile 1"|DS = "C:\Users\Vayeate\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\qekfxcdm.Unnamed Profile 1"
  Keyword: "PrefF"|FU = "C:\Users\Vayeate\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\qekfxcdm.Unnamed Profile 1\prefs.js"|DS = "C:\Users\Vayeate\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\qekfxcdm.Unnamed Profile 1\prefs.js"
  Keyword: "MetroPrefF"|FU = "C:\Users\Vayeate\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\qekfxcdm.Unnamed Profile 1\metro-prefs.js"|DS = "C:\Users\Vayeate\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\qekfxcdm.Unnamed Profile 1\metro-prefs.js"
  Keyword: "PrefDL"|FU = "Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [nsIProperties.get]"|DS = "Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [nsIProperties.get]"
  Keyword: "ExtPrefDL"|FU = "Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [nsIProperties.get]"|DS = "Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [nsIProperties.get]"
  Keyword: "PrefDOverride"|FU = "C:\Users\Vayeate\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\qekfxcdm.Unnamed Profile 1\preferences"|DS = "C:\Users\Vayeate\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\qekfxcdm.Unnamed Profile 1\preferences"
  Keyword: "ProfD"|FU = "C:\Users\Vayeate\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\qekfxcdm.Unnamed Profile 1"|DS = "C:\Users\Vayeate\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\qekfxcdm.Unnamed Profile 1"
  Keyword: "ProfLD"|FU = "C:\Users\Vayeate\AppData\Local\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\qekfxcdm.Unnamed Profile 1"|DS = "C:\Users\Vayeate\AppData\Local\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\qekfxcdm.Unnamed Profile 1"
  Keyword: "UChrm"|FU = "C:\Users\Vayeate\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\qekfxcdm.Unnamed Profile 1\chrome"|DS = "C:\Users\Vayeate\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\qekfxcdm.Unnamed Profile 1\chrome"
  Keyword: "UsrSrchPlugns"|FU = "C:\Users\Vayeate\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\qekfxcdm.Unnamed Profile 1\searchplugins"|DS = "C:\Users\Vayeate\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\qekfxcdm.Unnamed Profile 1\searchplugins"
  Keyword: "LclSt"|FU = "C:\Users\Vayeate\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\qekfxcdm.Unnamed Profile 1\localstore.rdf"|DS = "C:\Users\Vayeate\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\qekfxcdm.Unnamed Profile 1\localstore.rdf"
  Keyword: "UPnls"|FU = "Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [nsIProperties.get]"|DS = "Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [nsIProperties.get]"
  Keyword: "UMimTyp"|FU = "C:\Users\Vayeate\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\qekfxcdm.Unnamed Profile 1\mimeTypes.rdf"|DS = "C:\Users\Vayeate\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\qekfxcdm.Unnamed Profile 1\mimeTypes.rdf"
  Keyword: "cachePDir"|FU = "Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [nsIProperties.get]"|DS = "Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [nsIProperties.get]"
  Keyword: "BMarks"|FU = "C:\Users\Vayeate\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\qekfxcdm.Unnamed Profile 1\bookmarks.html"|DS = "C:\Users\Vayeate\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\qekfxcdm.Unnamed Profile 1\bookmarks.html"
  Keyword: "DLoads"|FU = "C:\Users\Vayeate\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\qekfxcdm.Unnamed Profile 1\downloads.rdf"|DS = "C:\Users\Vayeate\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\qekfxcdm.Unnamed Profile 1\downloads.rdf"
  Keyword: "SrchF"|FU = "Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [nsIProperties.get]"|DS = "Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [nsIProperties.get]"
  Keyword: "XPIClnupD"|FU = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\browser"|DS = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\browser"
  Keyword: "indexedDBPDir"|FU = "Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [nsIProperties.get]"|DS = "Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [nsIProperties.get]"
  Keyword: "permissionDBPDir"|FU = "Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [nsIProperties.get]"|DS = "Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [nsIProperties.get]"
  Keyword: "Home"|FU = "C:\Users\Vayeate"|DS = "C:\Users\Vayeate"
  Keyword: "TmpD"|FU = "C:\Users\Vayeate\AppData\Local\Temp"|DS = "C:\Users\Vayeate\AppData\Local\Temp"
  Keyword: "CurWorkD"|FU = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox"|DS = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox"
  Keyword: "Home"|FU = "C:\Users\Vayeate"|DS = "C:\Users\Vayeate"
  Keyword: "Desk"|FU = "C:\Users\Vayeate\Desktop"|DS = "C:\Users\Vayeate\Desktop"
  Keyword: "CurProcD"|FU = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\browser"|DS = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\browser"
  Keyword: "XCurProcD"|FU = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\browser"|DS = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\browser"
  Keyword: "XpcomLib"|FU = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\xul.dll"|DS = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\xul.dll"
  Keyword: "GreD"|FU = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox"|DS = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox"
  Keyword: "SysD"|FU = "C:\Windows\system32"|DS = "C:\Windows\system32"
  Keyword: "Trsh"|FU = "Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [nsIProperties.get]"|DS = "Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [nsIProperties.get]"
  Keyword: "Strt"|FU = "C:\Users\Vayeate\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup"|DS = "C:\Users\Vayeate\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup"
  Keyword: "Shdwn"|FU = "Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [nsIProperties.get]"|DS = "Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [nsIProperties.get]"
  Keyword: "ApplMenu"|FU = "Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [nsIProperties.get]"|DS = "Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [nsIProperties.get]"
  Keyword: "CntlPnl"|FU = "Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [nsIProperties.get]"|DS = "Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [nsIProperties.get]"
  Keyword: "Exts"|FU = "Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [nsIProperties.get]"|DS = "Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [nsIProperties.get]"
  Keyword: "Fnts"|FU = "C:\Windows\Fonts"|DS = "C:\Windows\Fonts"
  Keyword: "Prfs"|FU = "Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [nsIProperties.get]"|DS = "Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [nsIProperties.get]"
  Keyword: "Docs"|FU = "C:\Users\Vayeate\Documents"|DS = "C:\Users\Vayeate\Documents"
  Keyword: "ISrch"|FU = "Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [nsIProperties.get]"|DS = "Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [nsIProperties.get]"
  Keyword: "DfltDwnld"|FU = "C:\Users\Vayeate\Downloads"|DS = "C:\Users\Vayeate\Downloads"
  Keyword: "ULibDir"|FU = "Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [nsIProperties.get]"|DS = "Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [nsIProperties.get]"
  Keyword: "UsrDsk"|FU = "Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [nsIProperties.get]"|DS = "Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [nsIProperties.get]"
  Keyword: "LocDsk"|FU = "Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [nsIProperties.get]"|DS = "Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [nsIProperties.get]"
  Keyword: "UsrApp"|FU = "Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [nsIProperties.get]"|DS = "Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [nsIProperties.get]"
  Keyword: "LocApp"|FU = "Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [nsIProperties.get]"|DS = "Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [nsIProperties.get]"
  Keyword: "UsrDocs"|FU = "Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [nsIProperties.get]"|DS = "Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [nsIProperties.get]"
  Keyword: "LocDocs"|FU = "Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [nsIProperties.get]"|DS = "Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [nsIProperties.get]"
  Keyword: "UsrIntrntPlgn"|FU = "Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [nsIProperties.get]"|DS = "Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [nsIProperties.get]"
  Keyword: "LoclIntrntPlgn"|FU = "Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [nsIProperties.get]"|DS = "Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [nsIProperties.get]"
  Keyword: "UsrFrmwrks"|FU = "Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [nsIProperties.get]"|DS = "Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [nsIProperties.get]"
  Keyword: "LocFrmwrks"|FU = "Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [nsIProperties.get]"|DS = "Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [nsIProperties.get]"
  Keyword: "UsrPrfs"|FU = "Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [nsIProperties.get]"|DS = "Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [nsIProperties.get]"
  Keyword: "LocPrfs"|FU = "Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [nsIProperties.get]"|DS = "Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [nsIProperties.get]"
  Keyword: "Pct"|FU = "Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [nsIProperties.get]"|DS = "Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [nsIProperties.get]"
  Keyword: "Mov"|FU = "Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [nsIProperties.get]"|DS = "Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [nsIProperties.get]"
  Keyword: "Music"|FU = "C:\Users\Vayeate\Music"|DS = "C:\Users\Vayeate\Music"
  Keyword: "IntrntSts"|FU = "Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [nsIProperties.get]"|DS = "Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [nsIProperties.get]"
  Keyword: "WinD"|FU = "C:\Windows"|DS = "C:\Windows"
  Keyword: "ProgF"|FU = "C:\Program Files (x86)"|DS = "C:\Program Files (x86)"
  Keyword: "DeskV"|FU = "C:\Users\Vayeate\Desktop"|DS = "C:\Users\Vayeate\Desktop"
  Keyword: "Progs"|FU = "C:\Users\Vayeate\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs"|DS = "C:\Users\Vayeate\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs"
  Keyword: "Cntls"|FU = "Component returned failure code: 0x80520009 (NS_ERROR_FILE_INVALID_PATH) [nsIFile.create]"|DS = ""
  Keyword: "Prnts"|FU = "Component returned failure code: 0x80520009 (NS_ERROR_FILE_INVALID_PATH) [nsIFile.create]"|DS = ""
  Keyword: "Pers"|FU = "C:\Users\Vayeate\Documents"|DS = "C:\Users\Vayeate\Documents"
  Keyword: "Favs"|FU = "C:\Users\Vayeate\Favorites"|DS = "C:\Users\Vayeate\Favorites"
  Keyword: "Strt"|FU = "C:\Users\Vayeate\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup"|DS = "C:\Users\Vayeate\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup"
  Keyword: "Rcnt"|FU = "C:\Users\Vayeate\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Recent"|DS = "C:\Users\Vayeate\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Recent"
  Keyword: "SndTo"|FU = "C:\Users\Vayeate\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\SendTo"|DS = "C:\Users\Vayeate\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\SendTo"
  Keyword: "Buckt"|FU = "Component returned failure code: 0x80520009 (NS_ERROR_FILE_INVALID_PATH) [nsIFile.create]"|DS = ""
  Keyword: "Strt"|FU = "C:\Users\Vayeate\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup"|DS = "C:\Users\Vayeate\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup"
  Keyword: "DeskP"|FU = "C:\Users\Vayeate\Desktop"|DS = "C:\Users\Vayeate\Desktop"
  Keyword: "Drivs"|FU = "Component returned failure code: 0x80520009 (NS_ERROR_FILE_INVALID_PATH) [nsIFile.create]"|DS = ""
  Keyword: "NetW"|FU = "Component returned failure code: 0x80520009 (NS_ERROR_FILE_INVALID_PATH) [nsIFile.create]"|DS = ""
  Keyword: "netH"|FU = "C:\Users\Vayeate\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Network Shortcuts"|DS = "C:\Users\Vayeate\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Network Shortcuts"
  Keyword: "Fnts"|FU = "C:\Windows\Fonts"|DS = "C:\Windows\Fonts"
  Keyword: "Tmpls"|FU = "C:\Users\Vayeate\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Templates"|DS = "C:\Users\Vayeate\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Templates"
  Keyword: "CmStrt"|FU = "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu"|DS = "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu"
  Keyword: "CmPrgs"|FU = "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs"|DS = "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs"
  Keyword: "CmDeskP"|FU = "C:\Users\Public\Desktop"|DS = "C:\Users\Public\Desktop"
  Keyword: "CmAppData"|FU = "C:\ProgramData"|DS = "C:\ProgramData"
  Keyword: "AppData"|FU = "C:\Users\Vayeate\AppData\Roaming"|DS = "C:\Users\Vayeate\AppData\Roaming"
  Keyword: "LocalAppData"|FU = "C:\Users\Vayeate\AppData\Local"|DS = "C:\Users\Vayeate\AppData\Local"
  Keyword: "PrntHd"|FU = "C:\Users\Vayeate\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Printer Shortcuts"|DS = "C:\Users\Vayeate\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Printer Shortcuts"
  Keyword: "CookD"|FU = "C:\Users\Vayeate\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\INetCookies"|DS = "C:\Users\Vayeate\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\INetCookies"
  Keyword: "DfltDwnld"|FU = "C:\Users\Vayeate\Downloads"|DS = "C:\Users\Vayeate\Downloads"
  Keyword: "Docs"|FU = "C:\Users\Vayeate\Documents"|DS = "C:\Users\Vayeate\Documents"
  Keyword: "Pict"|FU = "C:\Users\Vayeate\Pictures"|DS = "C:\Users\Vayeate\Pictures"
  Keyword: "Music"|FU = "C:\Users\Vayeate\Music"|DS = "C:\Users\Vayeate\Music"
  Keyword: "Vids"|FU = "C:\Users\Vayeate\Videos"|DS = "C:\Users\Vayeate\Videos"
  Keyword: "Locl"|FU = "Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [nsIProperties.get]"|DS = "Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [nsIProperties.get]"
  Keyword: "LibD"|FU = "Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [nsIProperties.get]"|DS = "Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [nsIProperties.get]"
  Keyword: "XDGDesk"|FU = "Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [nsIProperties.get]"|DS = "Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [nsIProperties.get]"
  Keyword: "XDGDocs"|FU = "Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [nsIProperties.get]"|DS = "Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [nsIProperties.get]"
  Keyword: "XDGDwnld"|FU = "Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [nsIProperties.get]"|DS = "Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [nsIProperties.get]"
  Keyword: "XDGMusic"|FU = "Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [nsIProperties.get]"|DS = "Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [nsIProperties.get]"
  Keyword: "XDGPict"|FU = "Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [nsIProperties.get]"|DS = "Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [nsIProperties.get]"
  Keyword: "XDGPubSh"|FU = "Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [nsIProperties.get]"|DS = "Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [nsIProperties.get]"
  Keyword: "XDGTempl"|FU = "Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [nsIProperties.get]"|DS = "Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [nsIProperties.get]"
  Keyword: "XDGVids"|FU = "Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [nsIProperties.get]"|DS = "Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [nsIProperties.get]"
  Keyword: "DfltDwnld"|FU = "C:\Users\Vayeate\Downloads"|DS = "C:\Users\Vayeate\Downloads"
  Keyword: "DrvD"|FU = "C:"|DS = "C:"
  Keyword: "GreD"|FU = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox"|DS = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox"
  Keyword: "UpdRootD"|FU = "C:\Users\Vayeate\AppData\Local\Mozilla\updates\E7CF176E110C211B"|DS = "C:\Users\Vayeate\AppData\Local\Mozilla\updates\E7CF176E110C211B"
  Keyword: "XREExeF"|FU = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe"|DS = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe"
  Keyword: "ProfDS"|FU = "C:\Users\Vayeate\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\qekfxcdm.Unnamed Profile 1"|DS = "C:\Users\Vayeate\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\qekfxcdm.Unnamed Profile 1"
  Keyword: "ProfD"|FU = "C:\Users\Vayeate\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\qekfxcdm.Unnamed Profile 1"|DS = "C:\Users\Vayeate\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\qekfxcdm.Unnamed Profile 1"
  Keyword: "GreD"|FU = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox"|DS = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox"
  Keyword: "XCurProcD"|FU = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\browser"|DS = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\browser"
  Keyword: "XREExeF"|FU = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe"|DS = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe"
  Keyword: "UpdRootD"|FU = "C:\Users\Vayeate\AppData\Local\Mozilla\updates\E7CF176E110C211B"|DS = "C:\Users\Vayeate\AppData\Local\Mozilla\updates\E7CF176E110C211B"
  Keyword: "UAppData"|FU = "C:\Users\Vayeate\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox"|DS = "C:\Users\Vayeate\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox"
  Keyword: "XREExtDL"|FU = "Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [nsIProperties.get]"|DS = "Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [nsIProperties.get]"
  Keyword: "XREExeF"|FU = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe"|DS = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe"
  Keyword: "started"|FU = "Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [nsIProperties.get]"|DS = "Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [nsIProperties.get]"
  Keyword: "ProfDS"|FU = "C:\Users\Vayeate\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\qekfxcdm.Unnamed Profile 1"|DS = "C:\Users\Vayeate\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\qekfxcdm.Unnamed Profile 1"
  Keyword: "started"|FU = "Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [nsIProperties.get]"|DS = "Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [nsIProperties.get]"
  Keyword: "ProfLDS"|FU = "C:\Users\Vayeate\AppData\Local\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\qekfxcdm.Unnamed Profile 1"|DS = "C:\Users\Vayeate\AppData\Local\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\qekfxcdm.Unnamed Profile 1"
  Keyword: "XRESysLExtPD"|FU = "Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [nsIProperties.get]"|DS = "Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [nsIProperties.get]"
  Keyword: "XRESysSExtPD"|FU = "Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [nsIProperties.get]"|DS = "Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [nsIProperties.get]"
  Keyword: "XREUSysExt"|FU = "C:\Users\Vayeate\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Extensions"|DS = "C:\Users\Vayeate\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Extensions"
  Keyword: "XREAppDist"|FU = "Component returned failure code: 0x80520015 (NS_ERROR_FILE_ACCESS_DENIED) [nsIFile.create]"|DS = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\distribution"
  Keyword: "UpdRootD"|FU = "C:\Users\Vayeate\AppData\Local\Mozilla\updates\E7CF176E110C211B"|DS = "C:\Users\Vayeate\AppData\Local\Mozilla\updates\E7CF176E110C211B"
  ```

I only pasted Win8.1 for relative path profile above, for the rest I'm collecting them here in the comments: https://gist.github.com/Noitidart/715840fa5008ee032017 as Stack Overflow doesnt allow this much text.